# compiling error with vector in c++

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

I'm stuck! I have this very simple test code and I can't get it to compile! I have used the same code many times before but now it won't work!
I have this simple program

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "Rswap.h"
using namespace std;
int main(){
Rswap test();
    cin.get();
return 0;}
```

And then the rswap.cpp...

```
#include <vector>
#include "Rswap.h"
Rswap::Rswap(){
    V.push_back(9);
};
```

And then the rswap.h...

```
#ifndef Rswap_h
#define Rswap_h


class Rswap{
public:
  vector<int>V;
  Rswap();
};
  #endif
```

I'm using Visual studio 2008. Is there something wrong that is obvious and I'm missing or what could it be! As I said I have used this snippet on several differnet occassions and I can't find any difference between this and those that work...
 And i have tried both 
`vector < int > V`; and `vector <int> V;` without any luck

I have stared at this blindly now for some while so I thought it's better to ask here!

```
rswap.h(7) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
    rswap.h(7) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
    rswap.h(7) : error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
```

Comment: Quick question - tried `vector<int> V`? (Space in between ">" and "V".)

Comment: This probably won't fix your problem, but it's better practice to include the `#include <vector>` in the rswap.h file, where you need it - forcing all clients of rswap to know to do this is rude, and possibly impractical.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but note that `Rswap test();` declares a *function* returning a `Rswap` object. To declare a `Rswap` object, use `Rswap test;` (no parentheses).

Comment: @Philipp ,oops that was a TYPO from earlier tests..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the point you `#include "Rswap.h"`, you haven't declared `using namespace std;` yet, so the reference to `vector` in Rswap.h must be qualified with a namespace. Simply declare the vector with a namespace prefix.

```
class Rswap{
public:
  std::vector<int>V;
  Rswap();
};
```

Also, I suggest you `#include <vector>` from Rswap.h rather than relying on whoever uses Rswap.h to get the `#include` order right.

Comment: This fixes the problem But I know I have done this without the std:: prefix!

Comment: And that's because I have declared namespace std before that in the earlier versions just like You said! Thanks... I new it was something simple!

Comment: Just to be clear, header files should never have namespace declarations, and they probably shouldn't be included after namespace declarations either.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
  std::vector<int>V;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, your `using namespace std` comes too late - it should be inserted BEFORE the rswap.h include. In any case, it's MUCH better to write std::vector instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to #include <vector> in rswap.h.